# Filter in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database, filter

I have a `mysql` table for my records like

```
id int(11) | name varchar(255) | status enum('Yes', 'No', 'Nil') | type enum('auto', 'manual') |
```

I need a query to show all the records with manual type regardless of their status and all other records whose status is set as Yes

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is a simple OR condition. This will meet all 'manual' types or any records that has the status of 'Yes':

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE type = 'manual' OR status = 'Yes'
```

EDIT: Your conditions are as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE type IN ('manual', 'auto') OR (type = 'auto' AND status = 'Yes')
```

If you simplify this query you will get the first one.

Comment: what if I want to select all he records that are of type `auto OR manual` but `status = yes` should be checked only for the records with type `auto`

Comment: The first query meets all your conditions.